# Calculate height from two right angled triangles sharing an edge

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I am trying to calculate the perpendicular distance of a unicycle-like robot from a wall using two successive measurements from an ultrasonic sensor. The problem is modelled as shown:

(EDIT). The Robot is currently at position $A$. First it measures $AD$ then it moves a negligible distance(So that remains it at $A$) and measures $AC$. 
[image]

I want to calculate the length of $AB$ (perpendicular distance from the wall $BC$) knowing the lengths $AD$ and $AC$ (Which I can easily get from the sonar sensor). Also the angle ABC is $90$ degrees .
Thanks

Comment: Do you know any other angle, or any other distance?

Comment: @EricTowers Unfortunately no: I only have the lengths of AD and AC

Comment: Then all you can say is that the length of $AB$ is less than the lengths of $AC$ and $AD$.  TO see this mechanically, slide the wall a little further away and let $AC$ and $AD$ pivot at $A$ to fall down in contact with the wall again.  Keep moving and they can keep pivoting.

Comment: If you know the distance between $C$ and $D$ the problem can be solved.

Comment: Or the angle $\angle CAD$, which could in principle be measured locally at the robot.

Comment: I agree with @David, given that the robot has moved from $C$ to $D$, isn't it possible to know the distance?

Comment: So, it moves a negligible distance, *and* it turns, right?  (Otherwise why are $C$ and $D$ separated by a nonnegligible distance?)

Comment: We need an angle or distance $CD$ please.